# rake -D time doesn't work!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Here's an example of me running rake -D time

```
526:project 526$ rake -D time
rake time:zones:all
    Displays all time zones, also available: time:zones:us, time:zones:local -- filter with OFFSET parameter, e.g., OFFSET=-6

526:project 526$
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's running exactly how it should! 
Here's the output from about the -D flag that I get by running `$ rake -h`

```
-D, --describe [PATTERN]         Describe the tasks (matching optional PATTERN), then exit.
```

You just need to run `rake time:zones:all` or `rake time:zones:us`.